# Is there a way to fire a method from the press of the convenience key using android?

Tags: java, android

Is it possible to have my android application start a method from pressing of the convenience key when the application in focus?

On my phone the convenience key is a button located on the right hand side of the phone. I would like to be able to know if the user presses any of the buttons on the phone, even the volume would work.

Comment: Please contact the manufacturer of your phone, as only they know what this "convenience key" is.

Comment: @CommonsWare any of the buttons on the side of the phone, they are placed there for convenience, for example the volume

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are welcome to override `onKeyDown()` on your `Activity` and [watch for a `KeyEvent` of interest](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html). Note that not every key in the `KeyEvent` JavaDocs is accessible this way (e.g., power). Also note that it is possible that some specific `View` that is aware of these keys might consume the event first, though that is relatively unlikely for anything that matches your description of a "convenience key".

Comment: I am able to capture the volume up and down `KeyEvent`.